# How to ignore case when using TextBox to filter listview

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

Is there way of modifying the TextChanged event for a `TextBox` to ignore the case that has been entered? Currently in my `ListView` (containing town names) with a `TextBox` I want to search for any town name I want without having to use capital letters.

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
         {
             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
             {
                 this.ListTowns.ItemsSource = this.listItemTowns;
             }
             this.ListTowns.ItemsSource = this.listTowns.Where((item) => { return item.TownTitle.Contains(txtSearch.Text); });
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```cs
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
    {
        this.ListTowns.ItemsSource = this.listItemTowns;
    }
    else
    {
        this.ListTowns.ItemsSource = this.listTowns.Where(item => item.TownTitle.Contains(txtSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following should do the trick:

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
             {
                 this.ListTowns.ItemsSource = this.listItemTowns;
             }
             this.ListTowns.ItemsSource = this.listTowns.Where((item) => { return item.TownTitle.ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToLower()); });
}
```

You can case cast your strings either .ToLower() or .ToUpper().

Take care

Comment: don't suggest `ToLower()` it's a bad practice, use `StringComparison`  instead. refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN